# What is a word to describe an action that was not prompted by any special/specific occasion?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, you might give a birthday gift or a wedding gift, but a gift that wasn't one of those might be a ______ gift.

Comment: If it wasn't prompted by any particular occasion, you could call it a ***spontaneous** gift* - or just a ***gift***.

Comment: What if it's not spontaneous either? In the case I'm concerned with, it's prompted by a conversation, not an occasion. I want to find a word that can clarify.

Comment: In that case, as both myself and Josh61 have suggested, it's just a *gift*. You surely don't suppose English is going to have different adjectives specifically for identifying gifts which were given as a result of a conversation, a thought which just occurred to the giver, guilt because you forgot to give a birthday present, etc.? Or is there some *specific* reason why the gift was given, that might make a difference here?

Comment: ...whimsically, you might call it [an unbirthday gift](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+unbirthday+gift%22), as dozens of writers have in Google Books.

Comment: It doesn't quite apply to the volition behind a gift, but something pleasant that just happens can be **serendipity**

Comment: I spent some time with the thesaurus, and found more words that are close, but they all come with unwanted connotations or extra meaning (e.g. "gratuitous", "undue", "impromptu"). To @FumbleFingers' point, I suppose there is probably no word for this.

Comment: skiggety: Actually, I quite like ***impromptu** gift* for your context. I know it's not the "real" etymology, but for me it definitely has echoes of *not **prompted / occasioned** by anything specific*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think we are thinking along similar lines. "Impromptu" is definitely the best of the not-quite-right words I have found. And after I found out that "unoccasioned" actually _is_ a word, I notice that you landed on the word "occasioned".

Comment: My wife's grandmother called those "happy day gifts". She wasn't fond of planning to give something on a special occasion; she'd rather find the happenstance perfect things and then give them as she found them. We still do that in our family. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more time with search engines and thesauri, I think I answered my own question:

**[unoccasioned](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unoccasioned)**

> adjective
>
> Not occasioned, without occasion or cause.

(oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: Just be aware that the term is not common. I've never heard of an "unoccasioned gift."

Answer (score 2):

What about saying it was an "ad hoc" gift?

The adjective [ad hoc](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%20hoc) means:

> made or done without planning because of an immediate need

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Hi, uklancs. Welcome to English Language and Usage. We encourage answers with a link/research/reference that can support your explanation. Your original post was too short and it could be flagged for its length. I edited your post and see how it was done (by clicking on *edited X minutes ago* above my username). Please try to follow the format. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

***[Just](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/just)*** a gift:

> - only, ​simply.

(Cambridge Dictionary)